# Using nested ‘not in’ subqueries, but it just seems wrong. Advice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A snapshot of the relevant tables is as follows:
[image]

The purpose of this DB is to generate groups of samples (batches) from a list of available samples, then add the results from the batched samples (as place holders) to a result table. The list of samples assigned to a method is listed in the `method_sample` table.

I have written 2 queries that selects the next 20 available samples not already in the result table. The first query inserts into the `batch_sample` table, and a subsequent query inserts into the `result` table. Up till now, it’s all good.

The complication arises because **individual results** can be flagged as requiring dilution and then the **whole sample** must become available again in the next batch of samples. If the current result table looks like:

| result_id | compound_id | batch_sample_id | dilution_required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | false |
| 2 | 101 | 10 | **true** |
| 3 | 102 | 10 | false |
| 4 | 100 | 11 | false |
| 5 | 101 | 11 | false |
| 6 | 102 | 11 | false |

Then, after the next batch (before results are entered), it should look like:

| result_id | compound_id | batch_sample_id | dilution_required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | false |
| 2 | 101 | 10 | false |
| 3 | 102 | 10 | false |
| 4 | 100 | 11 | false |
| 5 | 101 | 11 | false |
| 6 | 102 | 11 | false |
| 7 | 100 | 10 | (null) |
| 8 | 101 | 10 | (null) |
| 9 | 102 | 10 | (null) |
| 10 | 100 | 12 | (null) |
| 11 | 101 | 12 | (null) |
| 12 | 102 | 12 | (null) |

For the `batch_sample` table, the query I’ve written is:

```
 INSERT INTO batch_sample ( method_id, batch_id, sample_id )

 SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 @methodID, @batchID, sample.sample_id 
 FROM method_sample
 INNER JOIN sample ON method_sample.sample_id = sample.sample_id
 LEFT JOIN batch_sample ON sample.sample_id = batch_sample.sample_id 
 WHERE method_sample.method_id = @methodID
 AND sample.sample_id NOT IN
 (
     SELECT sample_id
     FROM result
     INNER JOIN batch_sample ON result.batch_sample_id = batch_sample.batch_sample_id
     WHERE dilution_required = 0
     AND sample_id NOT IN
     (
          SELECT sample_id
          FROM result
          INNER JOIN batch_sample ON result.batch_sample_id = batch_sample.batch_sample_id
          WHERE dilution_required = 1
     )
 )
 ORDER BY sample_id;
```

It actually works, but this just looks wrong to me. So maybe someone can offer their opinion. Is there a better way to do this. I’ve tried the query with NOT EXISTS, but I couldn’t get it to work. This won’t be a large DB, maybe the `result` table will see 500,000 records.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If it returns the desired results how can it be wrong? How you structure your logic is up to what makes best sense to you surely?

Comment: BTW - have you heard of table aliases? You alias each table with a short (typically 1-3 character) label which you then use to refer to the table by... it makes queries far more reabable.

Comment: Your nested sub-query doesn't look like it does anything anyway? Your outer sub-query says `WHERE dilution_required = 0` and your inner one says `WHERE dilution_required = 1` so everything the inner sub-query would exclude is already excluded in the outer sub-query. Pretty sure you can remove it with no effect.

Comment: I need to ask: If a sample exists via a batch_sample in both dilution_required = 1 AND dilution_required = 0, should it be considered or not?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the question: *"If a sample exists via a batch_sample in both dilution_required = 1 AND dilution_required = 0, should it be considered or not?"* I created sample data, with the example provided, and filled in `batch_sample`.  Here sample `666`, was run in batches `711` and `717`

```
CREATE TABLE result (result_id int, compound_id int, batch_sample_id int, dilution_required int )
;
INSERT INTO result VALUES
  ( 1, 100, 10, 0),
  ( 2, 101, 10, 1),
  ( 3, 102, 10, 0),
  ( 4, 100, 11, 0),
  ( 5, 101, 11, 0),
  ( 6, 102, 11, 0)
;
CREATE TABLE batch_sample (batch_sample_id int, method_id int, batch_id int, sample_id int)
;
INSERT INTO batch_sample VALUES
  ( 10, 69, 711, 666),
  ( 11, 96, 717, 666)
;
```

Unfortunately, the subquery that tries to find a sample in both dilution_required = 1 AND dilution_required = 0 doesn't return anything. *We should return 666.*

```
 SELECT sample_id
 FROM result
 INNER JOIN batch_sample ON result.batch_sample_id = batch_sample.batch_sample_id
 WHERE dilution_required = 0
 AND sample_id NOT IN
 (
      SELECT sample_id
      FROM result
      INNER JOIN batch_sample ON result.batch_sample_id = batch_sample.batch_sample_id
      WHERE dilution_required = 1
 )
```

So, I'll try to answer the question: "Does a sample exist in both dilution_required = 1 AND dilution_required = 0?"

```
with
samples_dr0 as (
    select distinct sample_id, dilution_required
    from
        batch_sample bs
        join result r on
            bs.batch_sample_id = r.batch_sample_id
            and r.dilution_required = 0
),
samples_dr1 as (
    select distinct sample_id, dilution_required
    from
        batch_sample bs
        join result r on
            bs.batch_sample_id = r.batch_sample_id
            and r.dilution_required = 1
)
select dr0.sample_id
from
    samples_dr0 dr0
    join samples_dr1 dr1 on dr0.sample_id = dr1.sample_id
```

This yields the beast:

| sample_id |
| --- |
| 666 |

But now, observations:

- The dilution_required entries are set to 0 after inserting the next batch. I assume this is to remove false positives from the next selection cycle.
- Resetting dilution_required may be bad. You may want to analyze what methods or compounds cause dilution.
- If you want to keep dilution_required, you'll have to query the latest version of the results table...

the following sql finds samples that have dilution_required = 1 and dilution_required = 0, using the latest entries in results... allowing you to keep the original values unaltered.

see the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/isPkQ_FA

```
with
rmax as (
    select batch_sample_id, compound_id, max(result_id) result_id
    from result
    group by batch_sample_id, compound_id
),
latest_result as (
    select r.*
    from 
        result r
        join rmax on 
            r.batch_sample_id = rmax.batch_sample_id
            and r.compound_id = rmax.compound_id
            and r.result_id = rmax.result_id
),
samples_dr0 as (
    select distinct sample_id, dilution_required
    from
        batch_sample bs
        join latest_result r on
            bs.batch_sample_id = r.batch_sample_id
            and r.dilution_required = 0
),
samples_dr1 as (
    select distinct sample_id, dilution_required
    from
        batch_sample bs
        join latest_result r on
            bs.batch_sample_id = r.batch_sample_id
            and r.dilution_required = 1
)
select dr0.sample_id
from
    samples_dr0 dr0
    join samples_dr1 dr1 on dr0.sample_id = dr1.sample_id
```

Comment: Hi Papara! Sorry. I was not paying attention after I posted the question. I need to study want you did - thanks for taking a look! Hopefully I understood your question. Explaining it succinctly is hard. At any given point in time, a result should only have one `dilution_required` flag. The `dilution_required` is a temporary flag to indicate a compound result needs to be diluted (and this effectively means the whole sample needs to be diluted).

Comment: (Con't) Once a new batch is created to include the diluted sample (+ new samples), the `dilution_required` flag is cleared. The issue was selecting samples requiring dilution and new samples. That is, existing samples (in the same batch) in the result table (via batch_sample) may have `dilution_required` equal to 0 and 1. I only want to select the samples needing dilution. I hope it makes sense (I'm confused re-reading it)

Comment: Hi Papara! I should have read your answer before posting. You understood the problem perfectly. Having a two results for a single compound in a single sample is ok (actually required, so the results can be compared). They just can't be in the same batch. The results may be averaged or one result preferentially selected - but you are way ahead of me! Do you think using a temporary flag is a bad idea? It's sole purpose is to make a sample selectable again.

Comment: Hi Peter, I think the data model is ok as is. But updating dilution_required from 1 to 0 may be bad: you lose the info of which methods and compounds needed dilution, and that information can be important when designing your next round of tests. Also, if a sample only has one result and that one result has requires_dilution=1, will we rerun that sample? If so, the why must we also look for a result with requires_dilution=0 for the same sample?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the feedback! This'll be a very specialized DB for a very specific application. Each sample is always analyzed for a panel of ~200 parameters, so there'll never be just one result per sample. As for the loss of info, I do have a 'recursive' column (not shown) that points to the previous result id (if it has one). That way, I can trace it's history 'up the ladder' regardless of the number of repeats. I'm actually a chemist, so this is admittedly a bit of a hack. My knowledge is this area is shallow, but I couldn't find anything remotely suitable for our needs. So here we are...

Comment: So, is there a real need to query the results for dilution_result = 1 _AND_ dilution_result = 0? Does just checking for dilution_result = 1  suffice?

Comment: Yeah. The problem is if I use `dilution_required = 1`, that excludes new samples whose value for `dilution_required = null` as they've yet to be inserted into `result` table. I thought about using a `UNION` for two separate queries: one for the dilutions and one for the new samples, but that messes with `TOP`,

Comment: So, it seems you’re trying to manage a few concepts with the result table: 1. Candidate selection 2. Testing submitted 3. Testing completed.  You may want to consider modeling these in the `result` table with a `status` column; then you can cleanly delineate the relevant results. It’s also import to consider how to get the latest version of the result table. Study the `rmax` and `latest_result` CTE in my example. These tools should help model the process.

Comment: Agreed. I may be doing too much here. Maybe I'll break it up into smaller pieces. I will study what you've proposed. Thanks again for all your feedback. Much appreciated!